# Why imshow so slow

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to simply display a `68x68` array as image with a high frame-rate. I tried a lot , but i don't know how `set_data()` works? This code produces just 1 frame-per-second, that could not be, or?

You can see in the code, that i tried it, but it only shows a black-window, not the on/off switching dots ?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

switch = 0

plt.ion()  #to update the matplot image ???
plt.gray()

image = np.zeros([68,68])
image_data = plt.imshow(image, animated=True)


plt.show(block=False)


while True:
        if switch == 0:
                switch = 1
                image[0][0] = 1
                image[0][10] = 0
        else:
                switch = 0
                image[0][0] = 0
                image[0][10] = 1

        plt.imshow(image)
        #plt.draw()
        #image_data.set_data(image)
        plt.draw()
##      plt.show()
        print "other work starts here"
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: Do you want to make an "off-line" movie (i.e. a mpeg for example) or just to update the matplotlib-thing?

Comment: just update the live view window